Problema ordenación Xquery
Buenas tengo una duda de un ejercicio que tengo que hacer, me pide sacar una serie de institutos enumerados de 1 a 5 y que estén ordenados por código de centro, el problema que tengo es al ordenar las tuplas, ya que los valores de las posiciones se me altera.
> <table>{
> 
> for $centro at $i   in doc("centros.xml")//centros/centro where
> $centro/provincia="Málaga" or $centro/provincia="Almería" order by
> $centro/@id return
> <tr><td>{$i}</td><td>{$centro/@id}</td><td>{$centro/nombre/data()}</td></tr>
> 
> 
> 
> }</table>

y tengo esta salida
> <table>   <tr>
>     <td>4</td>
>     <td id="04700260"/>
>     <td>IES Aguadulce</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>3</td>
>     <td id="29010201"/>
>     <td>IES Belén</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>1</td>
>     <td id="29700114"/>
>     <td>IES Gerald Brenan</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>2</td>
>     <td id="29701210"/>
>     <td>IES Huerta Alta</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>5</td>
>     <td id="29701349"/>
>     <td>IES Playamar</td>   </tr> </table>

Y tendría que tener
> <table>   <tr>
>     <td>1</td>
>     <td id="04700260"/>
>     <td>IES Aguadulce</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>2</td>
>     <td id="29010201"/>
>     <td>IES Belén</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>3</td>
>     <td id="29700114"/>
>     <td>IES Gerald Brenan</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>4</td>
>     <td id="29701210"/>
>     <td>IES Huerta Alta</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>5</td>
>     <td id="29701349"/>
>     <td>IES Playamar</td>   </tr> </table>

Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? muchas gracias.

Utiliza
for $centro in doc("centros.xml")//centros/centro 
where $centro/provincia="Málaga" or $centro/provincia="Almería" 
order by $centro/@id
count $i
return <tr><td>{$i}</td><td>{$centro/@id}</td><td>{$centro/nombre/data()}</td></tr>

